# how to generate a gaussian distribution using mysql user-defined function

Tags: mysql, function, statistics, gaussian

I like to use MySQL to do quantitative analysis and statistics.
I would like to make a MySQL user-defined function of the form:
sample_gaussian(mean, stdev) that returns a single randomized
value sampled from a gaussian distribution having mean and standard
deviation of the user-entered arguments. MySQL already has a 
function rand() that returns a random number, so I just need to
know some pseudocode for constraining/transforming that value
so that it falls into the right distribution.
Any suggestions?

BTW- This is my first stackoverflow question, so please forgive
me if this question is asking too much of users on this site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In answer to my own question, here is a MySQL user-defined function that returns a single random value sampled from a Gaussian distribution with a given mean and standard deviation.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gauss;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION gauss(mean float, stdev float) RETURNS float
BEGIN
set @x=rand(), @y=rand();
set @gaus = ((sqrt(-2*log(@x))*cos(2*pi()*@y))*stdev)+mean;
return @gaus;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

To verify that this is in fact returning a Gaussian distribution, you can generate a series of these, then plot a histogram:

```
create temporary table temp (id int, rando float);
insert into temp (rando) select gauss(2,1); # repeat this operation 500 times
insert into temp (rando) select gauss(2,1) from any_table_with_500+_entries limit 500;
select round(temp,1), count(*) from temp group by round(temp,1) # creates a histogram
```

If you plot that histogram in excel or graphing tool of choice, you'll see the bell shaped normal curve.

Comment: I get the error "ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)" when I try to create the function. Do you have any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

rand() returns a uniformly distributed random variable between 0 and 1 (you should verify this because i am not sure - this is how it works in Sybase). You can use rand() to generate one or more normally distributed random variables r with mean zero and standard deviation (and variance) one, i.e. r ~ N(0,1), implementing one of the methods mentioned [here](http://www.sitmo.com/doc/Generating_Normal_Distributed_Random_Numbers)

When you have generated a random variable from N(0,1), you can de-standardize it (solve for X in the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardizing#Formula)) to get a random variable from N(my_mean,my_std), that is by multiplying it by my_std and then adding my_mean.

Comment: A list of algorithms is given by Wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution

Answer (score 1):

The [Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_muller) transform is a way to generate standard normal random variates using elementary functions.  It generates two at a time, which is sometimes wasteful, but I find it very elegant.