# Distribution of RAND() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't find anywhere in the documentation of MySQL whether RAND() function uses a uniform distribution or not. Does anyone know?

Comment: Jose please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360180/how-to-generate-a-gaussian-distribution-using-mysql-user-defined-function.

Comment: as far as i know its a uniform distribution but i cant find it in the docs

Comment: Are you asking just out of curiosity, or do you have a specific use-case that requires it? If so, please specify a bit more detail about that, as it may help with getting a useful answer.

Comment: @Spudley: In my case, I just want to output 100 random rows out of ~700. I know the SQL to do it. I'm just not sure that it is a uniform ditribution.

Comment: Over just 700 records, I doubt whether there will be any noticeable issues. If you were talking about 7 million, there might be some patterns that emerge due to it only being pseudo-random, but at scales like yours it's not going to be significant. If you're really desperate for something else, you could try ordering by the `MD5()` of the primary key (plus some kind of salt to make it unpredictable). `MD5()` has its faults (ie don't use it for passwords!), but is known to produce nicely evenly distributed values, so it would serve as an alternative if you didn't trust `RAND()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find the source code for the function quickly; seeing it might help get a better answer.  That said, it looks like a 'no.. but kinda close'.

From documentation I can see it tries to be random (and optionally you can seed it); but there are two caveats that mean it might not always be uniform when you expect it to the first issue is in it's documentation:

```
RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.
```

i.e. the code for it is questionable in being a true random number generator - it's good enough for most purposes, but can't be trusted for use in, say, encryption, and I'd wager can't be trusted to even be as uniform as you may expect.

Their claim that it's not perfect means it will almost certainly fail at least some of these tests; the how is still unclear, but if it's not a perfect RNG, you won't see a perfectly uniform distribution; I'd expect either gaps or peaks of ranges that are more/less common.
http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/cdrom/pscript/monkey.ps
(there's been other work since but this is still some of the key work in validating RNG's).

It'd wager that code behind it certainly does *not* try to guarantee a uniform distribution, since to do so (track history of what's come up already) would waste masses of memory.  In any case, if you've already generated a lot of values using a perfect RNG, nothing guarantees that if your values so far were all low the next one will be high.  It will always be just as random..