# How to generate true random numbers on Mysql

Tags: mysql, random

This is probably a very basic question and has been asked hundreds of times, but I looked for a solution and couldn't find any.

I have a table that has 1M records. I want to update the price column by generating a total random price from 1$ to 5000$ for each row. This is how I do it:

```
update `table` set price = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 5000);
```

Interestingly, when I get the AVG(price) from some specific WHERE Clauses I always get a number = ~5000/2. For example, if  price = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 5000) then AVG(price) = ~2500$, if price = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 2500) then AVG(price) = ~1250$, and so on. Any idea where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? If a random number generator has the same probability for all numbers and you take lots of numbers the average always is (max-min)/2.

Comment: I also don't see the problem here. Roll a dice 1000 times, your average score per roll would be 3.5 (max-min)/2 + min

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an answer just in mysql. In order to get "true" randomness, your system will need input from an outside source. Maybe you can have a sensor that detects ticks from a radioactive isotope, or you could read the low-order bits from a webcam feed to generate your numbers. But mysql's mechanisms are all pseudo-random; you won't find true randomness in the native APIs.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How about I generate max and min randomly? Any idea how using the same statement above? Thanks.

Comment: That's a uniform distribution. Were you expecting some other distribution, like normal or poisson?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, normal distribution.

Comment: Alright, that's a different though straightforward question. However, your random normal data will still have its average around the value you set as such. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Is this what you want? [how to generate a gaussian distribution using mysql user-defined function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360180/how-to-generate-a-gaussian-distribution-using-mysql-user-defined-function)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I want to have say 1M random numbers, and each time I get their average I have totally different value. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @Anonymous If you use the `gauss` function in the linked question, generate a random value for the `mean` parameter.